# UITableView empty view does not fit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've created an empty view .xib file to be displayed when the application is unable to download certain data from the internet.

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that when I set the empty view as my tableView's backgroundView, the empty view does not fit precisely into the screen.

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
-(void) updateUI
{
    if ([self.categories count]) {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    }else{
        NSArray* nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmptyView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView* emptyView = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        [emptyView sizeToFit];

        self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyView;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
}
```

I tried `[emptyView sizeToFit]` which didn't work. I also tried setting the frame of the empty view but I had no luck with that either. I'm fairly new to iOS development so I might have missed something really basic.

**Clarification:**

I did set Autolayout constraints on both labels in the Empty View:

The 'No categories available' is set to be in the centre of the view.

The instructions are set to appear a standard distance below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Auto Layout to set some constrains to the view, make sure that will fill the whole screen.

This tutorial of Auto Layout may help.
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout

Comment: I have added constraints to the both labels in the empty view. The 'No categories available' is set to be in the centre of the view. The instructions are set to appear a standard distance below.

Comment: I think your UILabel is too large to fit the window. You can change the controller'size in Stroryboard , maybe change it to 4.7-inch , Then press `Option+Command+=` to update the constrain ,  see what happen.

Comment: and you should set tow constrain of a distance between the edges of UILabel and the edges of the parent view to be equal or greater than to make sure the content of the UILabel won't overflow.

Comment: You need to add appropriate NSLayoutConstraint on your label, that means not center in container but leading and trailing.

Comment: Thanks so much! The leading and trailing constraints were what I was missing :)

Comment: @W.K.S You're welcome, if I solved your problem, you can vote.